# Meteor publish/subscribe example

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'am new to Meteor and just trying to make simple publish/subscribe sample work!

**server/main.js**

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
   // code to run on server at startup
});

var ServerCollection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
Meteor.publish("someData", function() {
   this.added('myCollection', 'myData', { name: "Bob" });
   this.ready();
});
```

**client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './main.html';

var ClientCollection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
Meteor.subscribe("someData");
console.log( ClientCollection.find().fetch() ); // Outputs an empty array :(
```

As a result I get an empty array in the console on the client side.
Also I'am running this sample on cloud9 vds.
I don't want to insert data to DB, just want to publish insensitive piece of data right to the client.

Could somebody help me please, this ez example drives mu nuts also there is lack of documentation and examples :(

Answer (score 0):

> The data is not ready yet when you call the console.log()

Yes, I fixed it by adding `Tracker.autorun` method.
Now it seems to work fine.

**client/main.js**

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import './main.html';

var ClientCollection = new Meteor.Collection("myCollection");
Tracker.autorun(() => {
   Meteor.subscribe("someData");
   console.log( ClientCollection.find().fetch() );
});
```

> You can refer a page from the official Meteor Documentation to get more information about how to handle Meteor subscription readiness.

This refers to Blaze templating, so there is nothing about how to handle it in client js. Anyway Meteor is lack docs and examples, also overwhelming for new users and poorly supported by the community which always redirects to the documentation even in case of simple questions. That's it.